# Change Meta Description on Click / Share with JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, meta

I have a page with various elements that look like this:

- Product Heading 1
- Product Image 1
- Product Description 1
- Share 1 Link
- Product Heading 2
- Product Image 2
- Product Description 2
- Share 2 Link
- Product Heading 3
- Product Image 3
- Product Description 3
- Share 3 Link

I want it so that when a user wants to share that product that the OG meta elements change based on what the user is sharing. So for example, the page may have a meta description of "some products for you" but when a user shares Product 2 the description would change to "description of product 2". Same with image/title/etc.

I have the following proof of concept I have put together form other threads on here, but it doesn't work. Well, the title portion changes, but the meta data does not.

The big challenge here is that a requirement is that this has to be accomplished in HTML and JS/Jquery - no PHP, no ASP, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>This title is not exciting</title>
<meta id="mtdesc" name="description" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content=""/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<button>Change description</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('button').on('click', function() {
    // Just replacing the value of the 'content' attribute will not work.
    $('meta[property="og:title"]').remove();
    $('meta[property="og:description"]').remove();
    $('meta[property="og:url"]').remove();
    $("head").append('<meta property="og:title" content="blubb1">');
    $("head").append('<meta property="og:description" content="blubb2">');
    $("head").append('<meta property="og:url" content="blubb3">');
    $("#mtdesc").attr("content","music all the time");
    $(document.title = "Now I've changed it");  
});

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say *"Just replacing the value of the 'content' attribute will not work."*. Why?

Here is an example -

```
$('button').click(function() {    
    $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content', 'foo');
});
```

I have set the content attribute of that meta tag to foo. No need to remove and append.

Comment: The comment in the code was actually there from the person who wrote this example. I must be doing something wrong still as when I view source, the meta information hasn't changed - is there a way for me to test it so I can see what meta data is being delivered? Perhaps viewing source from the browser is not the correct way.

Comment: Viewing the source is not the right way as the source is what comes from the server to your browser. To see the change you have to use the DOM inspector in your browser's developer tools. If you've never seen those just click on F12 while your browser has focus.